# How to figure C++ expression type on runtime?

Tags: c++, parsing, types, runtime, expression

I need to write a C++ code coverage program that takes in another C++ program (given in a file) and enhances or adds below to each of its statement a call to a function that increases a counter. But, I need to use a different counter for each type of expression (i.e. I need to figure how many expressions there are of each type). For this I need to figure the type of each C++ expression. IMO I need to use a parser API to parse each line to get its type.
Do you see a better solution?
Otherwise, where can I find parsing API?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want to consume a C++ parsing library.  Have it parse the file, then tweak the resulting AST, and then dump it back out as source code.  That's probably the most correct way to accomplish your task, and *it won't be easy*.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Are you perhaps looking for a [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29)?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to differentiate between the types?  THere's a lot of subexpression in a 25 line C++ function; do you intend to dump them all?

Comment: Thanks for your answers and comments. Please let me know, is it possible to use Boost.Spirit for parsing, adding my lines (i.e. transform) and creating a new code? 
I am going through Boost.Spirit's tutorial (Qi & Karma) to find the answer myself, but since I am short in time I would appreciate your comment to whether it is a possibility at all. Thanks!

Comment: Boost Spirit has no chance of parsing something like C++.  If you did succeed in parsing C++, Boost Sprit won't give you the type information you need for the discrimination you want.  Its the wrong solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A  "parser" API won't give you type information.  It will at best give you access to ASTs.

You need a full C++ front end, that can parse C++ code, do name and type resolution, and can compute the type, literally, of each expression.   On top of that, you need to insert the instrumentation that you want, and then spit out compilable source code.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) has all the capabilities necessary to do this.

DMS has been used to build test coverage and profiler tools for C++ (and many other languages); you can even download and try one to see what they are like.  You may find this paper on [building test coverage tools with DMS](http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf) interesting as a baseline for what you want to do.  Your variant needs the type inference but otherwise it isn't a lot different.

Comment: I don't always agree with Ira's recommendation of his products, but this is a clear case where it's beneficial. +1.